How can I achieve this bottom bar in React Native
I need to design this bottom tab in React Native, how can I achieve this?
I am trying to do it with React Native SVG but I'm not getting the desired results.
If possible, also suggest a solution to make it dynamic as when the focus is changed from the home circle, the change reflects on the focused one.

This is what I have tried so far. Using react native svg but this is not dynamic, i want it to adjust it dynamically with screen width
import React from 'react';
import {
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  Dimensions,
} from 'react-native';
import Svg, {Path} from 'react-native-svg';
import {useSafeAreaInsets} from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import {colors} from '../theme';

const {width: screenWidth} = Dimensions.get('screen');

const CustomTabBar = ({state, descriptors, navigation}) => {
  const insets = useSafeAreaInsets();

  return (
    <View style={[styles.tabContainer, {paddingBottom: insets.bottom}]}>
      {/* SVG Background with a curved design */}
      <Svg width={screenWidth * 2} height={85} style={styles.svgBackground}>
        <Path
          fillRule="evenodd"
          clipRule="evenodd"
          d={`M195 53.3992C214.856 53.3992 230.952 36.871 230.952 16.4825V16.4825C230.952 8.55662 237.197 -0.366875 245.074 0.507861L399.285 17.6319C404.816 18.246 409 22.9206 409 28.4852V77.2602C409 84.2963 403.296 90.0002 396.26 90.0002H-6.26001C-13.2961 90.0002 -19 84.2963 -19 77.2602V28.4852C-19 22.9206 -14.8157 18.246 -9.28518 17.6319L144.926 0.507809C152.804 -0.366929 159.048 8.55659 159.048 16.4825V16.4825C159.048 36.871 175.145 53.3992 195 53.3992Z`}
          fill={colors.palette.white}
          stroke={colors.palette.black}
          strokeOpacity={0.1}
          strokeWidth={4}
        />
      </Svg>

      {state.routes.map((route, index) => {
        const {options} = descriptors[route.key];
        const isFocused = state.index === index;
        const onPress = () => {
          if (!isFocused) {
            navigation.navigate(route.name);
          }
        };

        if (route.name === 'Home') {
          return (
            <TouchableOpacity
              key={route.name}
              onPress={onPress}
              style={styles.centerButton}
            >
              <View style={styles.centerIcon}>
                <Text style={{color: 'black', fontSize: 20}}></Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          );
        } else {
          return (
            <TouchableOpacity
              key={route.name}
              onPress={onPress}
              style={styles.tabButton}
            >
              <Text style={{color: isFocused ? 'yellow' : 'gray'}}>
                <Text style={{color: 'black', fontSize: 20}}></Text>
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          );
        }
      })}
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  tabContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    height: 70,
    position: 'relative',
  },
  svgBackground: {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 0,
    width: '100%',
    height: 80,
    zIndex: -1,
  },
  centerButton: {
    top: -25,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    borderRadius: 35,
    backgroundColor: 'yellow',
    shadowColor: 'black',
    shadowOffset: {width: 0, height: 4},
    shadowOpacity: 0.3,
    shadowRadius: 6,
    elevation: 10,
  },
  centerIcon: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    borderRadius: 25,
    backgroundColor: 'yellow',
  },
  tabButton: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});

export default CustomTabBar;



